# Mysql query is taking too long to load

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Am using Codeigniter for my project, in my database tables there are some columns with TEXT data type. I realized that loading those columns with TEXT data type takes too long to load.

My testing results:
These are TEXT data type columns - tc_status_1, tc_status_2, tc_status_3, tc_status_4, unconfirmation_status, tc_rejected_status, tc_restore_status, tc_confirmation_status

This is my CI code which takes too long to run it can even takes more than 20 minutes to run.

```
$this->db->select('application_id, tbl_application.first_name, tbl_application.middle_name, tbl_application.last_name, tbl_application.gender, admission_no, tbl_application.phone, tc_sent, tc_sent_1, tc_status_0, tc_status_1, tc_status_2, tc_status_3, tc_status_4, tc_application_status, tc_admission_status, is_confirmed, confirmation_status, confirmation_code, unconfirmation_status, tc_rejected_status, tc_restore_status, tc_confirmation_status, tc_verification_status, tc_transfer_status, programme_name, tc_code, form4_index, registration_status');
        $this->db->from('tbl_application');
        $this->db->join('tbl_academic_info', 'tbl_academic_info.applicant_id=application_id AND tbl_academic_info.status="0"');
        $this->db->join('tbl_admission', 'tbl_admission.applicant_id=tbl_application.application_id AND tbl_admission.status="0"');
        $this->db->join($this->db_name.'.tbl_programme', 'tbl_programme.programme_code=tbl_admission.program_of_study AND tbl_programme.status="0"');
        $this->db->where('tbl_application.branch', $branch);
        $this->db->where('tbl_application.academic_year', $entry_year);
        $this->db->where('tbl_application.admission_status', '1');
        $this->db->where('tbl_application.status', '0');
```

This code run faster.

```
        $this->db->select('application_id, tbl_application.first_name, tbl_application.middle_name, tbl_application.last_name, tbl_application.gender, admission_no, tbl_application.phone, tc_sent, tc_sent_1, tc_status_0, tc_application_status, tc_admission_status, is_confirmed, confirmation_status, confirmation_code, tc_verification_status, tc_transfer_status, programme_name, tc_code, form4_index, registration_status');
        $this->db->from('tbl_application');
        $this->db->join('tbl_academic_info', 'tbl_academic_info.applicant_id=application_id AND tbl_academic_info.status="0"');
        $this->db->join('tbl_admission', 'tbl_admission.applicant_id=tbl_application.application_id AND tbl_admission.status="0"');
        $this->db->join($this->db_name.'.tbl_programme', 'tbl_programme.programme_code=tbl_admission.program_of_study AND tbl_programme.status="0"');
        $this->db->where('tbl_application.branch', $branch);
        $this->db->where('tbl_application.academic_year', $entry_year);
        $this->db->where('tbl_application.admission_status', '1');
        $this->db->where('tbl_application.status', '0');
```

Any recommendation please! how can i handle that so that my code could run faster...

Comment: What exactly is stored in these TEXT columns? They all seem to have names like X_status_X which I would expect to have really short values but your issue would seem to indicate that they holds a ton of data

Comment: Also, how much faster is the second one running exactly?

Comment: X_status_X can hold long descriptions

Comment: Second one can only take some seconds to finish, not more than 5 to 6 seconds

Comment: Adding to the above, any time you find yourself with enumerated column names (above, say, 2), you can be reasonably confident that your schema design is suboptimal. Consider whether it's possible to place statuses in a separate table, e.g. statuses(id,tc_id,status)

Comment: I was loading many columns with TEXT data, so i solved the problem by loading only varchar data and other type but leaving TEXT data. So to load TEXT data i have to use read more button so that i can only load single row from the table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Use Indexes
2. By your code it seems you are populating a list of items, add in a view detail button/link to get the details for the application. Fetch only **Very Necessary** columns for your list. Other TEXT data can be displayed when user clicks on *View details* with a new query. New query will be getting all texts only for 1 application not for all the list
3. Re consider you database design, for all statuses that I believe are narrations, create a new table with a foreign key to that of application

Comment: I agree with Jawwad Ahmad. To improve performance of your query you have to take following points into consideration.
1. Fetch only necessary columns.
2. Indexing columns makes performance better.
3. Try to create Pivot table to maintain relations between tables.
4. If the data you are going to store into the DB does not have long value then use another datatype. I would like to recommend please read more about MySQL Datatype as well as Pivot table concept.

Comment: @JerrySam Please mark the answer as accepted if this resolved your problem. Thanks :)